# Get Netsuite Invoice all type line items using ODBC query

Tags: odbc, netsuite

I have tried to get invoice line items only. But, I am getting extra line items all the time. Now, I want to get the exact lin items that belong to that invoice. Please help me to filter out with extra line items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this   just fill the instance name of the ODBC

```
SELECT T.TRANSACTION_ID,I.NAME FROM TRANSACTIONS  T
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_LINES TL ON T.TRANSACTION_ID=TL.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN ITEMS I ON TL.ITEM_ID=I.ITEM_ID
where  T.TRANSACTION_ID=5582609
```